# How can I create an absolutely positioned environment position determined by parameters using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, parameters

I'm trying to define an environment that will place the contents in a `tikzpicture` `node` that gets positioned based on environment parameters. I'm very new to LaTeX, TikZ, and PGF, so the syntax is proving challenging.

Currently I have the following:

```
\NewEnviron{absnode}[2]
{
    \tikzset{%
        XPOS/.style={xshift=#1},
        YPOS/.style={yshift=#2}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[XPOS, YPOS, anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {%
        \BODY
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

I'm then trying to use it with:

```
\begin{absnode}{500 pt}{-10 pt}
Text inside the node positioned relative to the top left corner
\end{absnode}
```

This... isn't working. The above compiles, but the node does not appear to position except at the top left corner (with no shift applied).

What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot on `remember picture` and `overlay`. See page TikZ & PGF manual, pages 256--257.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this turns out to be forgetting the `[remember picture, overlay] arguments to`\begin{tikzpicture}`

With the below, it works as expected:

```
\NewEnviron{absnode}[2]
{
    \tikzset{%
        XPOS/.style={xshift=#1},
        YPOS/.style={yshift=#2}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[XPOS, YPOS, anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {%
        \BODY
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to effect this result.  Remember to run it twice.

Normally text is aligned by the baseline [anchor=base west].

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{absnode}[2]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \path (current page.north west) ++(#1,#2) node[anchor=north west] {\BODY};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{absnode}{500 pt}{-10 pt}
Text inside the node positioned relative to the top left corner
\end{absnode}

\end{document}
```